# Error Class 'kartik\widgets\SideNav' not found

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I have downloaded `yii2-widgets-master` and don't know where I should keep it.
I am facing the error `Class kartik\widgets\SideNav` not found.

My code is here

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\widgets\SideNav;
?>  
<div id = "links">
<div class="user-img"><a href = "" class="user"><i class="fa fa-user" aria- hidden="true"></i></a>
<div class="text-center info">  <p>Wecare</p></div>
</div>
<?php
$menuItems[] =  ['label' => 'DFenX - Yii2 User - '. Yii::t('app','User Admin     Panel'),  'icon' => 'cog', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/admin/index'])];
$menuItems[] =  ['label' => Yii::t('app','Authentication manager'),  'icon'    => 'th-list', 'items' =>  [    
['label' => 'Settings', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' => [
['label' => '/user/settings',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings'])],
['label' => '/user/settings/profile',     'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings/profile'])],
['label' => '/user/settings/account',     'url'=>Url::to(['user/settings/account'])],
['label' => '/user/settings/networks',   'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings/networks'])],
]],
['label' => 'Registration', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' => [                                
['label' => '/user/registration/register',     'url'=>Url::to(['/user/registration/register'])],
['label' => '/user/registration/resend',    'url'=>Url::to(['/user/registration/resend'])],
]],
['label' => 'Security', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' => [                                
['label' => '/user/security/login',   'url'=>Url::to(['/user/security/login'])],
['label' => '/user/security/logout',    'url'=>Url::to(['/user/security/logout'])],
]],
['label' => 'Recovery', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items'  => [                               
['label' => '/user/recovery/request',    'url'=>Url::to(['/user/recovery/request'])],
['label' => '/user/recovery/reset',   'url'=>Url::to(['/user/recovery/reset'])],
]],
]];
$type = SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY;
$heading = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> ' . Yii::t('app','USER    Admin - UTILITIES');
echo SideNav::widget([ 
'type' => $type,
'encodeLabels' => false,
'heading' => $heading,
'items' =>$menuItems,
]);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: How did u downloaded it?

Comment: downloaded it from third party.

Answer (score 0):

Add to composer.json:

```
"kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*"
```

Run `composer update` in console under project directory.